# mapping TIMESTAMPTZ to clickhouse datatype

Tags: clickhouse, cockroachdb

I have a TIMESTAMPTZ column in a cockroachDB source, by using clickhouse kafka consumer to read from cockroachDB changefeed i stored the TIMESTAMPTZ fields as DateTime however this resulted with inaccurate data, something of such sort:

1970-01-01 00:00:00

how to map TIMESTAMPTZ to the accurate date type in Clickhosue?

Comment: how did you configured your kafka consumer? What is kafka consumer? Table wioth Kafka engine?

Comment: try https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#date_time_input_format best_effort

Comment: yes it is  Table with Kafka engine. the issue is also that the string fields are empty too!

Comment: Then it's easy to solve with `besteffort`, with setting or using parsingBestEffort in MatView.

Comment: I think the issue is more complex than just having the date format fixed, all the messages I consume are empty! this is a detailed question about the issue:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187721/parsing-kafka-messages-using-clickhouse-kafka-engine i value your help if you could look into it

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the CRDB community!

I'm not very familiar with changefeed nor clickhouse but I'll try my best to help.

I tried to set up a CRDB changefeed on a table with a TIMESTAMPZ column:

```
create table t (i int primary key, j timestamptz);
insert into t values (1, now());
```

The output string of this TIMESTAMPZ columns uses ISO 8601 format:

```
root@localhost:26257/defaultdb> EXPERIMENTAL CHANGEFEED FOR t;
{"key":"[1]","table":"t","value":"{\"after\": {\"i\": 1, \"j\": \"2023-01-16T14:44:01.337341Z\"}}"}
```

So following @Denny Crane's [lead](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#date_time_input_format), it does seem like using `best_effort` will allow Clickhouse to parse input date/time in ISO 8601 format.

Can you try and let us know whether it helps? If not, I can engage my colleague who have more expertise on this matter to help you.